# Is VPC-native GKE cluster production ready?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

This happens while trying to create a VPC-native GKE cluster. Per the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips) the command to do this is

`gcloud container clusters create [CLUSTER_NAME] --enable-ip-alias`

However this command, gives below error.

`ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) Only alpha clusters (--enable_kubernetes_alpha) can use --enable-ip-alias`

The command does work when option `--enable_kubernetes_alpha` is added. But gives another message.

```
This will create a cluster with all Kubernetes Alpha features enabled.
- This cluster will not be covered by the Container Engine SLA and 
should not be used for production workloads.
- You will not be able to upgrade the master or nodes.
- The cluster will be deleted after 30 days.
```

**Edit**: The test was done in zone asia-south1-c

My questions are:

1. Is VPC-Native cluster production ready?
2. If yes, what is the correct way to create a production ready cluster?
3. If VPC-Native cluster is not production ready, what is the way to connect privately from a GKE cluster to another GCP service (like Cloud SQL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command seems correct. Seems like something is going wrong during the creation of your cluster on your project. Are you using any other flags than the command you posted?

When I set my Google cloud shell to region  europe-west1
The cluster deploys error free and 1.11.6-gke.2(default) is what it uses.

You could try to manually create the cluster using the [GUI](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/) instead of gcloud command. While creating the cluster, check the “Enable VPC-native (using alias ip)” feature. Try using a newest non-alpha version of GKE if some are showing up for you.

Public documentation you posted on [GKE IP-aliasing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/alias-ips?hl=en_US&_ga=2.74197778.-1049903467.1549893455) and the [GKE projects.locations.clusters](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters#Cluster.IPAllocationPolicy) API shows this to be in GA. All signs point this to be production ready. For whatever it’s worth, the feature has been posted last May In Google Cloud [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-vpc-native-clusters-for-google-kubernetes-engine).

What you can try is to update your version of Google Cloud SDK. This will bring everything up to the latest release and remove alpha messages for features that are in GA right now.

```
 $ gcloud components update
```

Comment: Issue is resolved. Based on your findings I tried creating a cluster with IP-aliasing via console and it worked fine. Next I checked my gcloud version in my VM and noticed that it was pretty old ````Google Cloud SDK 163.0.0````. ````gcloud components update```` does not work anymore. So I updated the gcloud sdk via a ````yum update```` after which the cluster creation worked fine from command line as well.